# NPE when i submit the jar to Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I write a code to consume stream from Kafka and then sink it back to another kafka topic.
The code runs normally in my IDE ,but when i submit the jar to Flink webpage, it throws NullPointerException on `String[] cells = s.split(",");`

Any help is appreciated. The full exception is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.lang.String.split(String.java:2273)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.split(String.java:2364)
    at ex_filter_operation$SplitterKafkaString.map(ex_filter_operation.java:336)
    at ex_filter_operation$SplitterKafkaString.map(ex_filter_operation.java:330)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:717)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:692)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:672)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:30)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collect(StreamSourceContexts.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:111)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractFetcher.emitRecordsWithTimestamps(AbstractFetcher.java:352)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaFetcher.partitionConsumerRecordsHandler(KafkaFetcher.java:185)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaFetcher.runFetchLoop(KafkaFetcher.java:141)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:755)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:213)
```

Comment: Most probably payload is null for some message.

Comment: it fails at the beginning

Comment: You really need to paste the code, but basically the `s` is probably null in the part You've pasted :)